# Sorting a time series in R after aggregation

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I have a time series, which measures a variable X each second and changes the GPS coordinates of the readings every 10 seconds. When I aggregate based on the GPS coordinates I loose the order of the time series, as in the following example:

```
 Input (loaded as variable stack in R):

 time,latitude,longitude,sensor_reading
 20150220081613,55.9516598,-3.2212117,2
 20150220081614,55.9516598,-3.2212117,3
 20150220081621,55.9516891,-3.2208011,5
 20150220081622,55.9516891,-3.2208011,3
 20150220081630,55.9516739,-3.2207998,2
 20150220081631,55.9516739,-3.2207998,3
```

Then I run the following command:

```
 aggregate(stack, by = list(stack$longitude, stack$latitude), FUN = mean)
```

And I get the following output, which has lost the order of the time series:

```
     Group.1  Group.2         time latitude longitude sensor_reading
 1 -3.221212 55.95166 2.015022e+13 55.95166 -3.221212            2.5
 2 -3.220800 55.95167 2.015022e+13 55.95167 -3.220800            2.5
 3 -3.220801 55.95169 2.015022e+13 55.95169 -3.220801            4.0
```

I solved the problem by indexing the rows and then sorting on their aggregates.

```
aggregate_file <- function(file, fun){
    # Get rows in order to sort after aggregation
    file$rows <- as.numeric(row.names(file))

    file_agg <- aggregate(file, by = list(file$longi, file$latitude), FUN = fun)

    # Order based on aggregates of the rows
    file_agg_ordered <- file_agg[order(file_agg$rows),]
    file_agg_ordered
}
```

**Is there a more elegant solution with less code?**

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? What are you using for aggregating?

Comment: I have now edited the question to include my solution to the problem.

Comment: We still need sample input data and desired output to make the problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Avinash There is a reproducible example now. I am aggregating on the longitude and latitude.